# Плагин загрузки файлов plupload

Tags: jquery, javascript

Здравствуйте!

Для множественной загрузки файлов я пытаюсь использовать плагин [plupload](http://plupload.com/). Плагин хорошо работает, но теперь после выбора файлов мне необходимо установить параметры для скрипта - получателя файлов. Я пробовала сделать это, добавив к коду яваскрипт следующее:

```
uploader.bind('FilesAdded', function (up, files) {
    alert("привет");
    uploader.settings
        .multipart_params
        .foto_spisok_title = $("#foto_spisok_title")
        .val();
    uploader.settings
        .multipart_params
        .foto_spisok_date = $("#foto_spisok_date")
        .val();
    uploader.settings
        .multipart_params
        .foto_spisok_id = $("#foto_spisok_id")
        .val();
});
```

Но ничего не сработало, даже алерт. Весь код получается такой:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    // Convert divs to queue widgets when the DOM is ready
    $(function () {
        $("#uploader").pluploadQueue({
            // General settings
            runtimes: 'gears,flash,silverlight,browserplus,html5',
            url: 'upload.php',
            max_file_size: '100mb',
            chunk_size: '1mb',
            //unique_names : true,

            // Resize images on clientside if we can
            resize: {
                width: 320,
                height: 240,
                quality: 90
            },
            multipart: true,
            multipart_params: {
                param1: '5',
                param2: '3'
            },
            // Specify what files to browse for
            filters: [{
                title: "Image files",
                extensions: "jpg,gif,png"
            }, {
                title: "Zip files",
                extensions: "zip"
            }],

            // Flash settings
            flash_swf_url: '/plupload/js/plupload.flash.swf',

            // Silverlight settings
            silverlight_xap_url: '/plupload/js/plupload.silverlight.xap'
        });

        // Client side form validation
        $('form').submit(function (e) {
            var uploader = $('#uploader').pluploadQueue();
            uploader.bind('FilesAdded', function (up, files) {
                alert("привет");
                uploader.settings
                    .multipart_params
                    .foto_spisok_title = $("#foto_spisok_title")
                    .val();
                uploader.settings
                    .multipart_params
                    .foto_spisok_date = $("#foto_spisok_date")
                    .val();
                uploader.settings
                    .multipart_params
                    .foto_spisok_id = $("#foto_spisok_id")
                    .val();
            });
            // Files in queue upload them first
            if (uploader.files
                .length > 0) {
                // When all files are uploaded submit form
                uploader.bind('StateChanged', function () {
                    if (uploader.files
                        .length === (uploader.total
                        .uploaded + uploader
                        .total
                        .failed)) {
                        alert("привет");
                        $('form')[0].submit();
                    }
                });

                uploader.start();
            } else {
                alert('You must queue at least one file.');
            }

            return false;
        });
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Да научитесь пользоваться консолью, в конце-то концов!!! Напр.

```
$('#user').test();
```

Ясное дело что в ни в `javascript`, ни в `jQuery` нету такой функции (опустим пока регулярки), что делает браузер? Он это вам выводит в консоль:

[image: console screenshot in mozilla firefox FireBug plugin]

ссылка на это же изоб-ие в полном виде: [full image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OkZt6.png)

Comment: В консоли ни одной ошибки нет (

Comment: Всем спасибо, разобралась, надо было внимательнее читать раздел events (http://www.plupload.com/example_events.php) на сайте. Там подробно показано в коде, как правильно привязывать функции к событиям.